# foreach Laravel-5 <option select

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, foreach

I have tried a lot of variants of code and tried to find similar problem in other topics. So, i have table users where each user is having one city(stored as a number), and of course table city with id and name of city (40 cities is there).
When real user open his profile settings page I want his city to be selected and and displayed in form. In this example in user table "Alex" is having city"2". In table city: id "2" and name_ru "cityB".

If i try this:

```
@foreach(App\City::get() as $city)
<option value='{{ $city->id }}'>{{ $city->name_ru }}</option>
@endforeach
```

It shows only cities, but I need result like this:

```
<option  value="1" > cityA</option>
<option selected value="2" > cityB </option>
<option value="3" > cityC </option>
```

So the question is - How to make SELECTED only one tag OPTION, which VALUE is equal to number of that city, which is stored in table users for "Alex".

I thought about this, but it shows nothing:

```
@foreach(App\City::get() as $city)
@if($user->city ==1)
<option selected value="1" > {{ $city->name_ru }}</option>
@elseif($user->city ==2)
<option selected value="2" > {{ $city->name_ru }}</option>
....
@endif
@endforeach
```

If I try this:

```
@foreach(App\City::get() as $city)
@if($user->city ==1)
<option selected value="1" > {{ $city->name_ru }}</option>
@endif
@endforeach

@foreach(App\City::get() as $city)
@if($user->city ==2)
<option selected value="2" > {{ $city->name_ru }}</option>
@endif
@endforeach

@foreach(App\City::get() as $city)
@if($user->city ==3)
<option selected value="3" > {{ $city->name_ru }}</option>
@endif
@endforeach
```

I get:

```
<option selected value="2" > cityA</option>
<option selected value="2" > cityB</option>
<option selected value="2" > cityC</option>
```

Help please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
@foreach(App\City::get() as $city)
$selected = '';
if($city->id == 1)    // Any Id
{
    $selected = 'selected="selected"';
}
// $selected is initially empty and when the if criteria met it contains selected which make dropdown selected
<option value='{{ $city->id }}' {{$selected}} >{{ $city->name_ru }}</option>
@endforeach
```

**Edited:** fetching data from models like `App\City::get()` on view is not a good idea, instead fetch it on controller and pass it on to the view is the right way.

Comment: Mayank, thanks!! Your code gave me always cityA SELECTED, so I changed it. I think you will say this code is scary, but it works :) Here it is:
if($user->city ==1)
foreach(App\City::get() as $city)
{{$selected = ''}}
if($city->id == 1)
{{
$selected = 'selected=selected'
}}
endif
<option value='{{ $city->id }}' {{$selected}} >{{ $city->name_ru }}</option>
endforeach
endif

if($user->city ==2)
foreach(App\City::get() as $city)
{{$selected = ''}}
if($city->id ==2)
{{
$selected = 'selec.........

Answer (score 7):

You should not use Model Queries inside your view as it is a bad practice as you're not following MVC Pattern. You can try this:

Inside your controller:

```
class UsersController extends Controller {
    public function users() {
        $users = User::with('city')->get();
        $cities = City::all();

        return view('view_name', compact('users', 'cities'));
    }
}
```

and inside your blade view, you can use `ternary operator` like this:

```
@foreach($users as $user)

    <select>

        @foreach($cities as $city)

            <option value="{{ $city->id }}" {{ ($user->city->id == $city->id) ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                {{ $city->name }}
            </option>

        @endforeach

    </select>

@endforeach
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Saumya,
I have:
class ProfileController extends Controller
{
public function edit()
{
$user = \Auth::user();
return view('profile.edit', compact('user'));
}}
Changed to:
public function edit()
{
$user = \Auth::user();
$users = User::with('city')->get();
$cities = City::all();
return view('profile.edit', compact('users', 'cities'));
}
But it gives me:
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2161: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::city()

Anyway thanks! 
Also I have solved it with help of Mayank and posted code below.. (code is scary but works:)

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="cities" id="cities">
<option value="">Select Cities</option>
@foreach($cities as $city){
<option value="{{$city->id}}{{($result->cityid==$city->id)?'SELECTED':''; ?>">{{$city->name}}</option>
}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, one should always add an explanation to it.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the `get()` method on your model, you are returning a collection.  So if you need the users city to be the first in the `select` input you can use the `except([])` collection method on the returned collection.

[Collection->except()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-except)

> The except method returns all items in the collection except for those with the specified keys

It goes without saying but try to query your models in the controllers (as mentioned by Saumya above).

```
class UsersController extends Controller {
    public function users() {
        $users = User::where('users.id', '=', \Auth::user()->id)
                         ->join('city', 'city.id', '=', 'users.city')
                         ->select('users.*', 'city.name_ru as city_name')
                         ->get();
        $cities = City::get();

        return view('users.settings', compact('users', 'cities'));
    }
}
```

```
<select>
    <option value="{{ $users->city}}">{{ $users->city_name }}</option>
    @foreach($cities->except([$users->city]) as $city)
        <option value="{{ $city->id }}">{{ $city->name_ru }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Another alternative is the `whereNotIn()` collection method:

[Collection->whereNotIn('key', [])](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-wherenotin)

> The whereNotIn method filters the collection by a given key / value not contained within the given array

```
<select>
    <option value="{{ $users->city}}">{{ $users->city_name }}</option>
    @foreach($cities->whereNotIn('id', [$users->city]) as $city)
        <option value="{{ $city->id }}">{{ $city->name_ru }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```