# Laravel/Blade: pre-selected dropdown option

Tags: html, laravel, forms, laravel-blade

I am using a `foreach` loop to generate a drop down list via [bensampo's ENUMS](https://github.com/BenSampo/laravel-enum) library, but I need to be able to preselect one of them as I have an edit view and I need it to load the option that is in my database.

My select in my edit view:

```
<select name="type" id="type" class="form-control">
    @foreach ($MailMessageTypes as $value =>$label)
        <option value="{{$value}}">{{$label}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

My function edit in my **MailMessageController**:

```
return view('MailMessage.edit', [
    'MailMessage' => $MailMessage],
    ["MailMessageTypes" => MailMessageType::toSelectArray()
]);
```

I tried to use the enum library's `getValues()` and `getKeys()` in the controller but that generates (duplicates) for me, since the `foreach` keeps generating all options.  I am using the select2 plugin

Added: I'm using the [select2 plugin](https://select2.org/) for the list.

Comment: You need to set the `selected` attribute on the specific option you want to select. I think this answer does it for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41101196/1024832

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your Edit page, you are passing the existing mail message as `$MailMessage`. I am assuming your database has its value as `id`, so it can be accessed as `$MailMessage->id`. While you are looping through and displaying each option, you need to check if that option's value equals the id of the message you are editing. If it matches, you set the [`selected` attribute on the `<option>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#attr-selected):

```
<select name="type" id="type" class="form-control">
    @foreach ($MailMessageTypes as $value => $label)
        <option value="{{$value}}" {{($MailMessage->id == $value) ? 'selected' : ''}}>
            {{$label}}
        </option>
     @endforeach
</select>
```

In your HTML your `<select>` would end up looking something like:

```
<select name="type" id="type" class="form-control">
    <option value="1">COM01</option>
    <option value="2" selected>COM02</option>
    <option value="3">COM03</option>
    // ... the rest of the options
</select>
```