# laravel 9 (how to bring a specific value from an array)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

i'm new to laravel and i want o bring a array value to my list

i think its easy to solve this

can you guys please help

```
<i data-acorn-icon="category"></i>
<select class="form-control" id="mes" name="mes" data-placeholder="Mês">
@php
$mes = [
    "1" => "Janeiro",
    "2" => "Fevereiro",
    "3" => "Março",
    "3" => "Abril",
    "3" => "Maio",
    "3" => "Junho",
    "3" => "Julho",
    "3" => "Agosto",
    "3" => "Setembro",
    "3" => "Outubro",
    "3" => "Novembro",
    "3" => "Dezembro"];

$valormes = $cliente->mes ;
@endphp
<option value="{{ $cliente->mes }}" selected>@php print_r($mes[$valormes]) @endphp </option>
    <option value="1">Janeiro</option>
    <option value="2">Fevereiro</option>
    <option value="3">Março</option>
    <option value="4">Abril</option>
    <option value="5">Maio</option>
    <option value="6">Junho</option>
    <option value="7">Julho</option>
    <option value="8">Agosto</option>
    <option value="9">Setembro</option>
    <option value="10">Outubro</option>
    <option value="11">Novembro</option>
    <option value="12">Dezembro</option>
</select>
</div>
```

this is the part with the problem
 `<option value="{{ $cliente->mes }}" selected>@php print_r($mes[$valormes]) @endphp </option>  doesnt bring the value.. getting error screen always`

Comment: Firstly, your php array needs to have unique keys for each element. You've re-used `"3"` for many of the elements.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what error are you getting?

Comment: This feels topical: [How to show selected value from database in dropdown using Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50970020/2943403) and [foreach Laravel-5 <option select](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41101152/2943403) and [Setting selected option in laravel form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38428324/2943403) and [Laravel-5 how to populate select box from database with id value and name value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29508297/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will solve your problem.

```
                <i data-acorn-icon="category"></i>
                <select class="form-control" id="mes" name="mes" data-placeholder="Mês">
                @php
                    $mes = [
                        '1' => 'Janeiro',
                        '2' => 'Fevereiro',
                        '3' => 'Março',
                        '4' => 'Abril',
                        '5' => 'Maio',
                        '6' => 'Junho',
                        '7' => 'Julho',
                        '8' => 'Agosto',
                        '9' => 'Setembro',
                        '10' => 'Outubro',
                        '11' => 'Novembro',
                        '12' => 'Dezembro',
                    ];
                    
                    $valormes = $cliente->mes;
                @endphp
                @foreach ($mes as $key => $m)
                    @if ($key == $valormes)
                        <option value="{{ $key }}" selected>{{ $m }}</option>
                    @else
                        <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $m }}</option>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
               </select>
             </div>
```

Comment: we're almost there..
showed all values except the "selected" $m

Comment: Check this out, type `@dd($cliente->mes)` anywhere on the page and tell what it returns.

Comment: its returning the right number of the specific month
i've used print_r either.. and its showing the number too

Comment: Then all you have to do is check the `$key` I'm editing the code and try again.

Comment: `if ($m== $valormes)` changed `if ($key == $valormes)`

Comment: perfect my friend, you are the best !